# One liner for operation with two different operators

Tags: c++, enums, operators, bitflags

I have a bitflag enum `EFlags`. Given a condition I want to either remove a flag or add a flag. I have defined the operator `|=` to add a flag and `&=` to remove a flag. For example, let us say the condition is `bool b_condition`:

```
EFlags flags;
bool b_condition = true;

if(b_condition)
  flags |= EFlags::FLAG;
else
  flags &= EFlags::FLAG;
```

I can easily convert this into a one liner with the following:

```
b_condition ? (flags |= EFlags::FLAG) : (flags &= EFlags::FLAG);
```

I am wondering if there is a way to have `flags` on one side and `EFlags::FLAG` on the other. That is, only the operator is affected by the terneary:

```
flags (b_condition ? |= : &=) EFlags::FLAG;
```

This code is incorrect. It does not work. How can I do something like this?

My reasoning: I have a line of these (18 currently) and I believe it will help massively with readability as currently it looks rather cluttered and it is a bit difficult to analyze. Also, I would not like a function like `add_or_remove_flag_conditionally(EFlags& flag, EFlag modification_flag, bool b_add);` Where it removes if `b_add == false`. This is my current approach, but I prefer to see the code, not an abstraction.

As requested: minimum reproducible example

```
enum EFlags : uint8_t
{
    NONE    =  0,
    FLAG    =  1,
    FLAG1   =  2,
    FLAG2   =  4,
};
    
void operator|=(EFlags& a, EFlags b)
{
    a = (EFlags)(a | b);
}

void operator&=(EFlags& a, EFlags b)
{
    a = (EFlags)(a & ~b);
}

int main()
{
    EFlags flags = NONE;
    const bool b_condition = true;
    b_condition ? (flags |= EFlags::FLAG) : (flags &= EFlags::FLAG);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that will unnecessarily complicate things. What you have now is better(in terms of readability) than what the proposed/seeked snippet.

Comment: `flags (b_condition ? |= : &=) EFlags::FLAG;` is hardly readable imo.

Comment: a function: `add_or_remove(flags,condition,EFlags::FLAG)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I specifically do not want that as said in the question. That is my current approach, and I am looking for something more direct.

Comment: @user12002570 Sure with a single example it is hardly any good. But as these pile on and with some spacing it will become much easier to read the code overall.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. I know it works somehow, but I dont remeber how and I dont get `flags |= EFlags::FLAG;` to compile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Sure! I have added the example.

Comment: ok, thats a very different story now. I assumed built in `|=` and `&=`, and my answer is now partly wrong. I don't know if I will fix it. Maybe later. Please consider that a [mcve] should be present from the start. Details matter. If you dont show code, we have to guess and this time I guessed wrong

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Sorry! I did mention I defined those operators, so I figured I didn't need more than that. I see you have deleted your answer so I will reiterate a comment I posted on it for other viewers of the question:

Since operators are really just functions, I figure I should be able to use a ternary to pick one conditionally. Much like: `condition ? foo() : bar();`.

Comment: Given that your example starts with 0, what is the point of using the `&=` operator here? You can just simplify to `if (b_condition) flags |= FLAG;`. Nice and readable.

Comment: @Botje that is a short coming of the example, I am afraid. `flags` could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

`|=` and `&=` are no objects that you can use as operands for the conditional operator. Though, `operator|=` and `operator&=` are:

```
 (b_condition ? (operator|=) : (operator&=))(flags,EFlags::FLAG);
```

Whether this is more readable is subjective of course. Just be prepared to some resistance during code reviews. Note that the conditional operator is actually not just a drop-in replacement for an `if-else` but there are things that can be expressed with the conditional operator that cannot be expressed with an `if-else`. This isnt one of them.

Comment: Yeah, `? :` probably does the conversion.

Comment: >  You cannot choose between |= and &= via the ternary operator without wrapping them in some function or similar though

That is valuable insight. I figured since operators are really just functions, I *should* be able to pick one conditionally with a ternary. I suppose I was incorrect, though.